# Filtering out empty tags in XML with C#

Tags: c#, xml, tags

So I am using this code to parse a gigantic (80,000 line) XML document. However when it was handed to me it added unnessecary rows due to parent nodes(which was fixed by the if statement in the code), and now it is doubling up on empty nodes.

Whenever I hit an empty node it will double up on the node before it... for example here is a peice of the xml:

```
<edit>
    <who>Jim Johnson(Jim.m.Johnson@google.com)</who>
    <when>2010-08-18T12:14:33.613Z</when>
    <description></description>
</edit>
```

And the data feed I am getting ends up looking like:

```
who                Jim Johnson
when               8/18/2010
description        8/18/2010
```

Anyone have a good idea as to how to trim off those empty tags?
Here is a peice of the code that is generating this table.

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(
{
    // Parse the file and display each of the nodes.
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                elementName = reader.Name;
                switch (elementName)
                {
                    //display my title stuff
                }
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                elementText = reader.Value;
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
            case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                if (elementName == reader.Name)
                {
                    contractRowArray1[0] = elementName;
                    contractRowArray1[1] = elementText;
                    contractRow = contractTable.NewRow();
                    contractRow.ItemArray = contractRowArray1;
                    contractTable.Rows.Add(contractRow);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
case XmlNodeType.Element:
    elementName = reader.Name;
    elementText = null;                  // ADDED
    switch (elementName)
    {
        //display my title stuff
    }
    break;
```

...

```
case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
    if (elementName == reader.Name && elementText != null)       // MODIFIED
    {
        contractRowArray1[0] = elementName;
        contractRowArray1[1] = elementText;
        contractRow = contractTable.NewRow();
        contractRow.ItemArray = contractRowArray1;
        contractTable.Rows.Add(contractRow);
    }
    break;
```

Comment: I have already tried that, for the blank tags elementText is equal to the previous text, so it never is made null. Through the program elementText is only mentioned 3 times, 2 times are in the code segment I posted and the only other time is intialization. Actually I did not have the top part when I put the null check, lemme see if adding that works without getting rid of all the information.

Comment: Seems to have worked, I am still confused how after setting it null and never changing the value again it did not wipe out all the data.... but I suppose it works! thanks! :D

Comment: When it starts a new node, it needs to wipe out previous state.  In  this case, you need to wipe out the previous element's text when you start a new element.

Comment: I realize now after some research that reader only reads a part of a line, I assumed for each run through of the while(reader.read()) read a whole line, like <csm> blah </csm> but I realize now it reads <csm> runs it, then blah, then </csm> Seems odd. Anyways, thanks again!

Comment: One final question if you could possible answer this, there are data objects inside my XML like this: <who xsi:nil="true" /> What kind of XmlNodeType is this? It seems to be running as an Element, and I cant figure out how to differentiate this type of element from just <who> type of elements.